# Page repeats after turning page using Python Requests and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests, web-crawler

I want to get as many EU law files in [this website](https://op.europa.eu/en/search-results?p_p_id=eu_europa_publications_portlet_facet_search_result_FacetedSearchResultPortlet_INSTANCE_TTTP7nyqSt8X&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=localnav&p_p_col_pos=2&p_p_col_count=4&queryText=China&facet.collection=EUWebPage&facet.collection=EULex&resultsPerPage=10&sortBy=RELEVANCE-DESC&SEARCH_TYPE=SIMPLE&) as possible, and if possible, convert them into .txt format.

However, I don't know how to simulate the change of QUERY_ID in the url when turning the page (differs when page is turned). The resulting problem is that after turning some pages,  the page generated from my url remains unchanged even though the pages are not the same. For these unchanged problematic url, I got different result each time I refresh it.

My code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
# ua = UserAgent()
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

# https://op.europa.eu/en/search-results?p_p_id=eu_europa_publications_portlet_pagination_PaginationPortlet_INSTANCE_gDBsAazqs5X2&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&queryText=China&facet.collection=EUWebPage&facet.collection=EULex&sortBy=RELEVANCE-DESC&SEARCH_TYPE=SIMPLE&QUERY_ID=278762364&&resultsPerPage=50&startRow=1&QUERY_ID=278762364
#https://op.europa.eu/en/search-results?p_p_id=eu_europa_publications_portlet_pagination_PaginationPortlet_INSTANCE_gDBsAazqs5X2&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&queryText=China&facet.collection=EUWebPage&facet.collection=EULex&sortBy=RELEVANCE-DESC&SEARCH_TYPE=SIMPLE&QUERY_ID=278762569&&resultsPerPage=50&startRow=51&QUERY_ID=278762569
# https://op.europa.eu/en/search-results?p_p_id=eu_europa_publications_portlet_pagination_PaginationPortlet_INSTANCE_gDBsAazqs5X2&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&queryText=China&facet.collection=EUWebPage&facet.collection=EULex&sortBy=RELEVANCE-DESC&SEARCH_TYPE=SIMPLE&QUERY_ID=278762572&&resultsPerPage=50&startRow=101&QUERY_ID=278762572
pre_url = 'https://op.europa.eu/en/search-results?p_p_id=eu_europa_publications_portlet_pagination_PaginationPortlet_INSTANCE_gDBsAazqs5X2&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&queryText=China&facet.collection=EULex&facet.collection=EUWebPage&sortBy=RELEVANCE-DESC&SEARCH_TYPE=SIMPLE'
if not os.path.exists('./EU-law'):
    os.mkdir('./EU-law')

index = 601
# bro = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./Chromedriver')
bro = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
# bro = webdriver.Safari()
for i in range(601, 10000, 50):
# for i in range(1, 12, 10):
    url = pre_url + '&QUERY_ID=' + str(278762572 + 5*i) + '&&resultsPerPage=50&startRow=' + str(i) + '&QUERY_ID=' + str(278762572 + 5*i)

    print('url: ', url)
    page_text = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers).text

    tree = etree.HTML(page_text)

    li_list = tree.xpath('//*[@id="portlet_SearchResults_SearchResultsPortlet_INSTANCE_66jcMJpeURua"]/div/div[2]/div/div/ul/li')
    file_name_list = tree.xpath('//*[@id="portlet_SearchResults_SearchResultsPortlet_INSTANCE_66jcMJpeURua"]/div/div[2]/div/div/ul/li//h2/a/span')

    check(i, li_list, file_name_list, url)

    bro.get(url)
    # tn_list = bro.find_elements("xpath", '//*[@id="portlet_SearchResults_SearchResultsPortlet_INSTANCE_66jcMJpeURua"]/div/div[2]/div/div/ul/li/div/div[1]/h2/a')

    for i in range(50):
        btn_list = bro.find_elements("xpath",'//*[@id="portlet_SearchResults_SearchResultsPortlet_INSTANCE_66jcMJpeURua"]/div/div[2]/div/div/ul/li/div/div[1]/h2/a')
        btn_list[i].click()
        bro.implicitly_wait(2)
        sleep(1)
        btn1 = bro.find_elements("xpath", '//*[@id="portlet_publicationDetails_PublicationDetailsPortlet"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/button')

        if len(btn1) == 0:
            print('Doc', index, '没有reference, 跳过')
            index += 1
            bro.back()
            continue

        btn1[0].click()
        bro.implicitly_wait(2)
        sleep(5)
        detail_text = bro.page_source
        reference_tree = etree.HTML(detail_text)
        html_url = reference_tree.xpath('//*[@id="citation-content"]/a/text()')
        if html_url:
            html_url = html_url[0]
        else:
            print("有reference，但没有链接")
            continue

        # //*[@id="citation-content"]/a
        bro.back()
        # bro.navigate().refresh()
        print('最终url：', html_url)
        text_page = requests.get(url=html_url, headers=headers).text
        # bro.get(html_url)
        # text_page = bro.page_source
        text_tree = etree.HTML(text_page)
        text_list = text_tree.xpath('//*[@id="document1"]/div//p/text()')
        if len(text_list) == 0:
            print('骚瑞，citation链接里找不到文件！')
            index += 1
            bro.back()
            bro.get(url)
            continue
        title = text_tree.xpath('//*[@id="title"]/text()')[0]
        title = title[0:200].replace('/', '*') + '....txt'

        law_path = './EU-law/' + title
        if os.path.exists(law_path):
            print('Doc', index, '已经有了，跳过')
            index += 1
            continue
        fp = open(law_path, 'a', encoding='utf-8')
        for p in text_list:
            p = p.replace(u'\xa0', ' ')
            fp.write(p)
            fp.write('\n')

        print('doc', index, ': ', title, '下载成功！')
        index += 1
    # bro.quit()

print('完成！！')
```

I have been stucked here for quite a while. Does anyone know what's the problem? Much appreciated.

I tried to define a formula for the change of the query id, such as add 5 each time I turn the page. But it doen't work.

I wonder whether the problem relates to the header.

Comment: Thanks for your reminder, now you can see my code.

Comment: when you say "the page generated from my url remains unchanged" are you talking about `requests.get` or `bro.get`?